# How to send a char array over serial which includes a NULL char?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, wiringpi

I am using [WiringPi-Python](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python) to send data over serial and trying to send a char array. My problem is; I cannot send the data if the array includes a **0** (NULL char).

```
bytes = [112, 52, 0, 18]
send = "".join(map(chr, bytes))
wiringpi.serialPuts(serial, send)
```

How can I pass a NULL contained char array to `serialPuts`?

Comment: Could you improve your question by adding more details? I get no errors nor warnings while I run your code.

Comment: The code runs without an error. I am scoping the output with an oscilloscope. If there is not a NULL char in the array, the data is ok. But if there is a NULL, cannot see rest of the data (after NULL). (serialPuts stops sending if sees a NULL char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the problem is in [`bindings.i`](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python/blob/2fcaeaf2767daae08478c5ab29dd51ef6c84bbf1/bindings.i) of the library:

`serialPuts()` is defined as

```
extern void serialPuts (const int fd, const char *s) ;
```

and in C, strings (`char*`) are terminated by the `\0` character. I consider that a bug of the library. It should be

```
extern void serialPuts (const int fd, const char *s, int strlen) ;
```

Try `wiringpi.serialPutchar()` in a loop.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using 'serialPutchar()', because the timing between 'serialPutchar()'s is not fixed.For example, if I send "hello world" with 'serialPuts()' it takes a fixed time to send all, but if I send it char by char with 'serialPutchar()' in a loop, the total time to send "hello world" fluctuates.

Comment: I recompiled the library according to your advice. Works like a charm. Thank you.